# Conditional Formatting using if clause

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to change the background color of a cell in excell based on if the cell in a different sheet is not null.

Is it possible to do this in a function?

My condition is this:

```
if(NOT(isBlank($Sheet1!I2), make green, make red)
```

Comment: I just wanted to show that there are more options available than only two states ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you solve it with Conditional Formatting?

Just create a new rule:

[image: Create new rule]

And then enter the formula with your check (for instance =Sheet2!$D$6<>""):

[image: Enter formula]

Create one rule for green fornmatting and one for red formatting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use in VB.Net to add conditional formatting, feel free to adapt it to your needs. In this case it's validating that certain cell has a value greater than 0. Remember that if you have some doubt about excel coding you can always record a new macro with the desired behavior and see the generated code.

```
range = sheet.Range("A1")
validations = range.Validation
validations.Add(Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateDecimal, _
                AlertStyle:=Excel.XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual, _
                Formula1:=0)
validations.InputTitle = String.Empty
validations.ErrorTitle = "Error: Select a decimal > 0"
validations.InputMessage = String.Empty
validations.ErrorMessage = "You must enter a decimal > 0"
```